# Изъявительное vs. сослагательное

Tags: наклонение

*(1) Было трудно представить, **что** мужчина ее круга женился на служанке.*

*(2) Было трудно представить, **чтобы** мужчина ее круга женился на служанке.*

Исправьте меня, если я неправа:

В (1) используется индикатив. Можно предположить, что действие придаточного было совершено (но это просто представить трудно).

В (2) используется сослагательное наклонение - здесь действие не было совершено, но рассматривается как предположение.

Или я все неправильно вижу?

Comment: Всё правильно.  Для сослагательного наклонения нужна либо частица "бы", либо союз "чтобы".

Answer (score 2):

Можно добавить, что в предложении (1) в изъявительном наклонении возможно разное время: Было трудно представить, что мужчина ее круга женился/женится на служанке.

В предложении (2) для образования сослагательного наклонения, обозначающего возможное действие, используется только форма "женился бы".

Comment: Вера, большое спасибо за это дополнение!!! оно меня на одну идею принесло!!! спасибо!!! : )

Answer (score 1):

Вы правы: во втором предложение действие рассматривается как гипотетическое.

В этом случае частица ***бы(б)***входит в состав союза чтоб(ы).

См.:  Русская грамматика.

Comment: Можно точную ссылку на "русскую грамматику"?

Comment: http://rusgram.ru/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5 - это что ли? Совершенно экспериментальный и сырой источник. Даже не хочу комментировать. В академической грамматике есть что-то подобное?

Comment: @Behemothus знаете, я связывалась с одним из автором этого источника и мне тоже советовали этот линк. можно спросить, что говорит против слияния "что" с частицей "бы" по Вашему мнению?

Comment: @Anonym, непременно свяжитесь с одним из "авторов этого источника" и скажите ему, что Бегемотус не советует больше давать этот линк. Бегемотус не любит источников, где использут непонятную терминологию. И еще Бегемотус никогда не говорил что он против слияния чего-то там. И за он тоже не говорил. Бегемотус просто не понимает, что означает "слияние" в понимании Anonym и/или "автора источника".

Comment: дорогой Behemothus, я надеюсь, Вы меня правильно интерпретируете... в силу моего юного возраста и небольшой подкованности в русском языке, я не осмеливаюсь ничего утверждать. у Richard Brecht я читала, что он рассматривает "чтобы" как слившийся (или как правильно сказать?.. so in English I would say „they fell together“) союз (союз "что" + модальная частица "бы") и мне просто было интересно узнать другие мнения...

Comment: Anonym, я надеюсь, родной у вас - русский? Тога возраст не имеет значения. Тут все равны. Тем более что я - полный дилетант, профессионально ни русским, ни каким другим языком кроме языков программирования не занимавшийся. . А кто такой Richard Brecht, боюсь, далеко не все знают. Я без Гугла, наверно, бы и не вспомнил, что слышал о нем что-то ранее. По сути я расписал всё, что имел против подхода КГ к этому вопросу.

Answer (score 1):

Отчасти правильно понимаете, но очень ограниченно.

Здесь - да можно так трактовать (опуская некоторые подробности), так, но в очень похожих предложения может быть и по-другому.

Если же строго подходить, то это не сослагательное наклонение. 
Вы смешиваете понятие *грамматической конструкции* и её семантическую роль.

Специального союза же для выражения сослагательного наклонения в русском нет. Поэтому грамматически в обоих случаях - наклонение обычное изъявительное. Но по смыслу второе можно трактовать как условное.

Грамматически сослагательное (условное) наклонение в русском выражается только одним способом - глагол в форме пошедшего времени (в соответствующем числе и роде) + частица "бы"("б"), возможно в отрыве от глагола.

Comment: behemothus, частица ''бы" может входить и в состав союза чтоб(ы).

Comment: Серж, а почему вы мне об этом сообщаете? И что из этого следует, даже если принять вашу трактовку?

Comment: Ну или хотя бы что вообще означает формулировка "частица входит в состав союза"? По вашему "чтобы" - составной союз? Или здесь у Вас что-то другое?

Comment: behemothus, чтобы то же самое, что ''что бы''. Просто в некоторых случаях она объединяется, и получается чтобы. В академической грамматике упоминается чтоб, что бы.

Answer (score 1):

Я вынужден дать разъяснения по поводу "слияния" и прочих наворотов "Корпусной грамматики".

//---

Сразу скажу, что независимых от КГ источников, полагающих, что сослагательное наклонение может выражаться с помощью одного только союза "чтобы" (без независимой от него частицы бы), я не нашел. А в рамках, скажем, ЕГЭ даже и искать не буду.

//---

С другой стороны, наделение в "Корпусной Грамматике" подобными свойствами одного только союза "чтобы", наименее характерного для всего ряда (кабы, дабы, будто бы и проч., которые даже не упоминаются), свидетельствует о бесконечной сырости источника.

//---

Вот одна статья, построенная явно под школу авторов ГК (автор статьи это и не скрывает), где *чтобы* рассматривается наряду с перечисленными в свете выбора форм выражения предиката условия.
http://www.dialog-21.ru/digests/dialog2015/materials/pdf/DobrushinaNR.pdf

Статья интересная, но автор, много всего говоря, так и не отвечает на ключевой вопрос, считать ли подобные конструкции сослагательным наклонением (а если нет, то чем считать вообще).
Вот как автор ставит вопрос:

> В настоящей статье будут обсуждены следующие вопросы.
>   Какие критерии могут быть применены для того, чтобы квалифицировать частицу бы в составе различных союзов (точнее было бы называть их союзными сочетаниями) как показатель сослагательного наклонения?
>   ...

Только дочитав статью понимаешь, что ответа на свой вопрос автор не дает. Т.е. критерии-то он перечисляет, но о результате их применения к реальным примерам благополучно умалчивает.))) Другие подобные источники даже не разбирал. Примерно то же самое.

//---

Далее. Разговоры о "слиянии" мне непонятны в принципе. Союз "чтобы" не относится к числу составных, а если говорить только об этимологии, то какое отношение это имеет к современной грамматике?

//---

И главное. В академической грамматике нет упоминания ни о подобных конструкциях как сослагательном наклонении, ни вообще о каких-то способах его образования, отличных от сочетания "частица + глагол".
http://rusgram.narod.ru/1922-1936.html
И обратите внимание, АК различает **сослагательное** и **условное** наклонения.

//---

*Маленькая оговорка.
Исторически эта конструкция соответствует асигматическому аористу от "быть" + причастие на "л", поэтому в исторических и стилизованных текстах возможно в первом лице что-то типа **"естьли быхЪ азъ делалЪ"**. 
Но это единственный, бесконечно устаревший вариант, помимо общепринятого, который можно отнести к сослагательному наклонению.*

//--

**Вывод**. Без должного переосмысления систематики всей грамматики сослагательного наклонения записывать рассматриваемую конструкцию в сослагательное как минимум преждевременно.

Comment: большое спасибо за линки и за Ваш труд и время!!! особое спасибо за указание на различие "сослагательное и условное наклонениe"! этим вопросом мне тоже надо в скором времени заниматься...
PD: родной язык у меня испанский...